# Brownian motion : Understanding the output of mvBM function.?

Tags: bioinformatics

To fit the brownian motion for independent evolution of traits i used below code:

```
rownames(carni)<-gsub("_",".",rownames(carni))  #Renaming to match the tip of tree
#Independent Evolution
brown_indepen <- mvBM(carni_tree,carni,param=list(constraint="diagonal"))
```

mvBM is the function from mvMORPH package. It seems by giving constraint="diagonal" would fit the model for traits to be evolved independently. I would like to know the idea behind it. Also, i got the below output after running the code. I would also like to know what below output means.

```
LogLikelihood:   -589.2373 
AIC:     1186.475 
AICc:    1186.771 
4 parameters 

Estimated rate matrix 
______________________ 
      size    range
size  73.70335  0.00000
range  0.00000 13.54524


Estimated root state 
______________________ 
       size    range
theta: 38.43947 13.78439
```

Size and range were the two traits.

Comment: This seems appropriate for the biology forum, but consider posting/migrating to statistics or bioinformatics--they may be more familiar with mvMORPH